# I can't use $ like a normal character in Code Template for maven pom.xml for Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to change code template (maven pom.xml) in IntelliJ idea from default to my own.

When I have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
        <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
        <version>${DS}{vavr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Intellij still resolves this line with `version` like:`<version>$VAVR.VERSION$</version>`.

According to the documentation IntelliJ should

> Treating dollar sign
>
> You can prevent treating dollar characters ($) in template variables as prefixes. If you need a dollar character ($ inserted as is, use the ${DS} file template variable instead. When the template is applied, this variable evaluates to a plain dollar character ($).

but it doesn't work correctly.

What should I do? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you try `$${vavr.version}`?

Comment: Yep, still the same result.

Comment: Feel free to report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.